# how does list of list of string can copy the value of a sublist

Tags: java, arraylist

is there any way to add a list A in a list of list B on iteration changing the list A everytime.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> totalFile = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> file = new ArrayList<String>();
while(fp.next()){

            file.add(fp.getString(1));
            file.add(fp.getString(2));
            file.add(fp.getString(3));
            file.add(fp.getString(4));
            file.add(fp.getString(5));
            file.add(fp.getString(6));

            totalFile.add(file);
            file.clear();
            System.out.println(totalFile);



        }
```

fp is resultSet.

i found that totalFile is making a reference to the file , but how can i copy a list A in a list of list B then clear the list A n populate it again n again copy list A to list of list B , and do that for n times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> totalFile = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
while(fp.next()){
        ArrayList<String> file = new ArrayList<String>();
        file.add(fp.getString(1));
        file.add(fp.getString(2));
        file.add(fp.getString(3));
        file.add(fp.getString(4));
        file.add(fp.getString(5));
        file.add(fp.getString(6));

        totalFile.add(file);
        System.out.println(totalFile);
}
```

Create a new `ArrayList` inside the loop; don't try reusing the same list.

Comment: Note that if `totalFile` was declared as `List<List<String>> totalFile` (which is how it _should_ be, because you should code to interfaces, not implementations), you could simplify the adding into a one-liner: `totalFile.add(Arrays.asList(fp.getString(1), fp.getString(2), fp.getString(3), fp.getString(4), fp.getString(5), fp.getString(6)));`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Sir ,thank u for the suggestion ,i'll keep that in mind

Comment: @Andrew what do you mean?